# There is no system image on this computer?

Tags: hard-drive, system-restore

So I am trying to reformat my hard drive with a system image disk. I use the options on the Recovery's advanced options.
I have 2 DVD-RW's with the system image. Two because one DVD wasn't big enough.

It restarts I get all the way to the point where it asks to insert a System image disk to start up I have my 1st System image disk in my drive.....but it doesn't read it and says no system image found!

Ether my computer being stupid and not reading the disk or I am doing something wrong. But I cant see what that would be.

I need to reformat my computer so I can sell the hard drive for a better one.

This is so annoying. I need help.

Is it because its a DVD-RW?  If so that's so stupid =-="

Answer (score 1):

Are you "booting" from the disk or using the Windows Recovery options.
I suspect you need to boot from the recovery disk...purely conjecture.

DVD-RW isn't the compatibility definer. Is it a DVD "+" or "-"? Some old DVD Drives wont read  one or the other.

(I would have posted this as a comment but lack the 50 rep)